# как удалить классы у нескольких элементов с одинаковыми классами jquery

Tags: jquery

как удалить классы у нескольких элементов с одинаковыми классами jquery.

Comment: Слева от ответов на Ваши вопросы есть знак "галочка". Он там для Вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.odinakovyj_klass').removeClass('drugoy_klass_1').removeClass('drugoy_klass_2');

$('.odinakovyj_klass').removeClass('drugoy_klass_1 drugoy_klass_2');

$('.odinakovyj_klass').removeClass(['drugoy_klass_1', 'drugoy_klass_2']);
```

https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Answer (score 1):

В jQuery если вы укажете класс (селектор) то все элементы с этим классом (селектором будут обработаны)

```
$('.some_klass').removeClass('class_to_delete');
```

Все элементы с классом some_class будут просмотрены и если у них есть class_to_delete то он будет удалён.
Способы передать классы для удаления

```
elem = $('.some_class');
//     последовательно вызвать метод 
elem.removeClass('class_1').removeClass('class_2').removeClass('class_2');
//     предать массив
elem.removeClass(['class_1', 'class_2','class_2']);
//     предать строку разделённую пробелами
elem.removeClass('class_1 class_2 class_2');
```